# What can be planted in this large cement planter?

Tags: trees, plant-recommendations

We have this long cement dividing planter (30”W x 20’ L) at the end of our driveway. It separates a parking spot from the back patio. I have had flowers and a veggie garden here as well. Both did well but I am toying with the idea of putting in something more substantial. Maybe something that acts as a screen, something evergreen, maybe even some kind of trees and tall grass??? Or at least little clean up in terms of leaves.
We live in Seattle, WA.the planter gets morning sun for about 4-5 hours but then is in a combination of sun, dappled shade and complete shade in the late [image]afternoon.
I’ve let it go the past couple years because I just can’t decide on anything. Your ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Does the concrete planter drain into the ground or is it mounted on a concrete base with occasional side drainage? To keep it simple it might be a perfect low maintenance container for the more invasive varieties of bamboo provided the roots/rhizomes cannot ever leave the bounds of the container of course? And you would have an endless supply of gardening canes !

Comment: Given the proximity to the basketball court, whatever you plant will be hit by an errant ball or three over the course of the season. What have you done in the past to protect the vegetables that you grew there?